# Issue with Conversion from struct to char *

Tags: c++, type-conversion, winsock2

I have a struct of size 57 bytes but when i convert to char *, the size of char * variable shows only 4 bytes. What is the problem with this?

Code:

```
struct overhead{

    unsigned char flags;
    unsigned short int seqNo, timeDiff, threshold, length;  

};    

struct payload{

    double forceX,forceY,forceZ,positionX,positionY,positionZ;

};


struct packet{

    overhead fields;
    payload data;

};

packet pack;

// Assigning some values to the struct members.

char * message = (char *)pack;

retval = send(conn_socket, message , sizeof(message), 0);
```

Edit:

At the receiver, the if the char * is typecasted into packet *, the strut members do not get the values as assigned at the sender. Why is this so?

Comment: that because on a 32bit system the size of char * IS 4 bytes...Size of pointer to struct not the same as sizeof struct

Comment: you probably want sizeof(packet)

Comment: And you'll have to format the data to the format expected at the other end.

Comment: What's the problem with `sizeof(char *)` being 4? What exactly did you expect, and why?

Answer (score 3):

char* is a pointer (i.e. a memory address) so will be 32 bit (on 32 bit platform); 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

`char*` is on a 32 bit machine 4 byte. So `sizeof(char*)` == 4. If you want the length you can use `sizeof(packet)`, see [here](http://ideone.com/8JQXyE).

In addition you should consider serializing your packets.

Answer (score 0):

`pack` is a pointer to a `char`.  The size of a pointer on 32 bit platforms is 4 bytes.  If you want the length of the data that `pack` points to, try [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/).